# heroku RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I use heroku,

```
git push heroku master
```

I got error

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to frozen-springs-63708.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/frozen-springs-63708.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozen-springs-63708.git'
```

sof search , and do it：
    RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

but a new bug come in.
coding ：

```
I, [2016-03-26T02:32:36.244283 #52076]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/zhangxiaodong/projects-deploy/ywlist3-heroku/public/assets/rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker-948429d2d71cda1ec511884b9acb61832b86e631e18567e9f25ae4839a447a24.css.gz
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#' (line: 14707, col: 0, pos: 408749)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:11936)
    at js_error (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:12155)
    at parse_error (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:13967)
    at Object.next_token [as input] (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:19118)
    at next (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:20436)
    at semicolon (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:21281)
    at simple_statement (/private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:24179)
    at /private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:22307
    at /private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2659:21493
    at /private/var/folders/83/ky9j032d2d1063_xd0y0hrth0000gn/T/execjs20160326-52076-37btgqjs:2660:1595new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2659:11936)
js_error ((execjs):2659:12155)
```

```
next ,what can I do ? .

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript files in your application? Is it possible that any of the code contains an error?

Comment: thank you, You are right, I change .js to .coffee, but not  use // to replace #, so error, Thank You Very Much.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I once got such an error from trying to deploy with mismatched brackets, so I wondered if it was a similar case.

Comment: yes, That is js problem. The prompt is clarity。and I am first meet it . Thank you very much.